# Requirements for a TM to halt

Tags: turing-machines

I'm just beginning self-studying a course on computability and automata; my textbook, describing a generic Turing Machine, lists two following halt conditions:

1. A TM halts, if for a particular state $q \in Q$, $\delta(q, a) = (q, a, HALT)$ for all $a$ in the alphabet and this $q$ is called a halt state;
2. A TM also halts, when the TM reads $a$ while being in $q$, and $\delta(q, a) = (q, a, HALT)$ is true *only for this particular $a$*.

I have no problems comprehending the first one, but I'm a little frustrated by the second one, that is, I don't understand, why the exclusivity of $a$ is of any importance. Won't the machine halt if we have several $a, a'$, for both of which it's supposed to halt?

And in general, are there any other halting conditions possible?

Comment: I feel like this is just how your book defines a TM to maybe simplify some later proofs. If you also allow multiple  $a$, i.e. - together with the other conditions - allow any amount of $a$, the $TM$ will still be functionally equivalent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally figured this out after some further research.

In this particular definition, one differentiates between halting states and a so-called "stalling action" or, rather, stalling with no further actions. The book of Robert Soare "Turing Computability" states:

> If the machine ever reaches the halting state $q_0$, after say $s$ steps, then we say $M$ halts and the output $y$ is the total number of 1’s on the tape. <...> We may assume that $M$ never makes any further moves after reaching state $q_0$, i.e., that the domain of $δ$ contains no element of the form $(q_0,s)$.

At the same time,

> if the machine M enters a state $q \ne q_0$ and reads a symbol $s$ from which $δ(q, s)$ gives no moves, then the machine **stalls**, i.e., makes no further moves, and gives no output. We **do not refer to this as halting** even though the machine stalls and stops forever. We use the term halting **only** if $M$ enters the halting state $q_0$.

This way, the first definition that I initially cited would be equivalent to "no symbol gives the machine an order for further moves in this particular halting state", and the second one was referring to this stalling condition, with a little of messed up terminology.

So if the function $δ(q, s)$ provides no image with $q \ne q_0$ for a particular symbol $s$, then it's considered to be an error for the symbol $s$.

With this definition, one doesn't need to declare the $δ$-function on the whole $Q \times S$ and provides a way to deal with these missing spots.

Answer (score 3):

The first condition makes no sense whatsoever to me, and neither condition is expressed in the most obvious way. I can't imagine why you'd ever want to define halting in that way.

**A Turing machine halts exactly when it enters the HALT state.**  It's as simple as that.  The only alternative I've ever seen is to have two halting states, corresponding to accepting and rejecting the input. In that case, the machine halts exactly when it enters either one of them.

Your source seems to be adopting a different approach, in which "HALT" is not a state but an action of the machine in the same class as "move the tape head left" or "move the tape head right". That's unusual, but not problematic in its own right. However, neither definition of halting is the one that I would expect.

- The second one is the closest: the machine halts if it decides to stay in its current state, leave the current character on the tape and make the HALT action. But this is still strange – surely the HALT action on its own should halt the machine, regardless of what state the machine moves to and what it writes on its tape at that step? For example, the behaviour of hte machine at the next step would seem to be undefined if $\delta(q,a)=(q',a',\mathrm{HALT})$ and $q'\neq q$ and/or $a'\neq a$.
- The first definition is very unnatural. I can see no motivation for saying that the machine halts only if it's in a state where seeing any character whatsoever would cause it to stay in the same state, leave the tape as it is and making the HALT action. In fact, this is basically defining the state to be a halting state in the way that Turing machines are usually defined. If one wanted to go down that route, why not just use the conventional HALT state instead of making HALT an action of the machine?

Note, however, that these definitions of halting, and the standard one, are all equivalent in that they can simulate each other. So, whichever of these definitions you use, the same class of problems can be computed by Turing machines.

Comment: Well, I understand the first one in the following way: not only it halts for a particular input, but it will halt for any letter of the alphabet, which makes this $q$ to a so to say "totally halting state" — it halts in this state whatever the input. This would be exactly the HALT state. 

However the textbook states, that it's possible for a TM to halt not only in that "total" HALT state, but in some different cases, where there should be a "specific letter that causes it to halt", maybe? So I still feel the possibility of having 2 different conditions, but don't understand the second one.

Comment: @JørgenSolheim OK but imagine that you're in a state where you go to HALT if you read $a$ and somewhere else if you read $b$. In the first definition of halting, if you read $a$, you transition to the HALT state, but you don't actually halt. Buhhh?

Comment: Edited the original question, there should've been no delta after the equal sign.

Comment: @JørgenSolheim That's a weird way to define halting. Essentially, that means "halt in state q if the next state must/may be HALT". Why should one halt one step earlier than HALT? Why not two steps, then? Or a million steps?

Comment: @chi Exaclty what I was thinking.

Comment: I'm starting to think that, perhaps, in this formalization HALT is not a state, but a "direction". I.e. the third element of the triple could be left/right/stay/halt. Then, halting states are those triggering the "HALT" direction. If that's the case, it's rather non standard, and more complex than needed.

Comment: @chi Ah, yes, I think you might be right. But then it seems that a state that says "halt if you read $a$, move left if you read $b$" has the bizarre behaviour of looping forever if you read $a$ in the first definition of halting!

Comment: @DavidRicherby Indeed, very bizarre. I guess the second definition is the intended one, while the first is another independent definition of "must-halting state". I wonder what the book actually says.

Comment: @chi Yeah. I've edited my answer to cover this definition of halting as a machine action (analogous to moving the head left/right) instead of having a halting state.